# Limit number of droppable dragged items inside a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I found this [code](http://www.mrgeek.me/technology/tutorials/jquery/how-to-accept-multiple-items-in-a-droppable-element-jquery/), and the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/caferdo/k5XJv/3/) that was linked.

This is close to what I am looking for, however I would like to add a counter because I would like list 2 and list 3 to only accept 3 draggable items.

I intend to add more lists to this code for my purposes and they also need to only accept 3 items.

List 1 needs to be able to accept all of the draggable items.

I think I need to create an array with a counter to keep track of all of this, but I don't know how to do that. I don't really understand or know javascript.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         $(".droppable").droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                var $list = $(this);
                $helper = ui.helper;
                $($helper).removeClass("selected");
                var $selected = $(".selected");                 
                if($selected.length > 1){                       
                    moveSelected($list,$selected);
                }else{
                    moveItem(ui.draggable,$list);
                }                                       
            }, tolerance: "touch"
         });

         $(".draggable").draggable({
            revert: "invalid",
            helper: "clone",
            cursor: "move",
            drag: function(event,ui){
                var $helper = ui.helper;
                $($helper).removeClass("selected");
                var $selected = $(".selected"); 
                if($selected.length > 1){   
                    $($helper).html($selected.length + " items");
                }                                       
            }
         });

        function moveSelected($list,$selected){
            $($selected).each(function(){
                $(this).fadeOut(function(){
                       $(this).appendTo($list).removeClass("selected").fadeIn();
                });                 
            });             
        }

        function moveItem( $item,$list ) {
            $item.fadeOut(function() {
                $item.find(".item").remove();
                $item.appendTo( $list ).fadeIn();
            });
        }

        $(".item").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("selected");
        });

    });
```

The HTML...

```
<div id="list1" class="droppable list"><!-- I want this to accept many. -->
        <div class="item draggable">1</div>
        <div class="item draggable">2</div>
        <div class="item draggable">3</div>
        <div class="item draggable">4</div>
    </div>
    <div id="list2" class="droppable list"><!-- I want this to accept only 3. -->
        <div class="item draggable">5</div>
        <div class="item draggable">6</div>
    </div>
    <div id="list3" class="droppable list"><!-- I want this to accept only 3. -->
        <div class="item draggable">7</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a `data-max` attribute for each droppable list and inside the `drop` function you can check if the number of elements inside that list reached the `max` (limit), and if so - just return false.

Here is the change to your code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var $list = $(this);
      $helper = ui.helper;
      
      // Check if we reached the maximum number of children. 
      if ($(this).children().length == $(this).data('max')) {
        return false;
      }
      
      $($helper).removeClass("selected");
      var $selected = $(".selected");                 
      if($selected.length > 1){                       
        moveSelected($list,$selected);
      }else{
        moveItem(ui.draggable,$list);
      }                                       
    }, tolerance: "touch"
  });

  $(".draggable").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
    drag: function(event,ui){
      var $helper = ui.helper;
      $($helper).removeClass("selected");
      var $selected = $(".selected"); 
      if($selected.length > 1){   
        $($helper).html($selected.length + " items");
      }                                       
    }
  });

  function moveSelected($list,$selected){
    $($selected).each(function(){
      $(this).fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).appendTo($list).removeClass("selected").fadeIn();
      });                 
    });             
  }

  function moveItem( $item,$list ) {
    $item.fadeOut(function() {
      $item.find(".item").remove();
      $item.appendTo( $list ).fadeIn();
    });
  }

  $(".item").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  });

});
```

```css
div.list {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
  min-height: 20px;
}
div.list div {
  background: gray;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="list1" class="droppable list" data-max="-1"><!-- I want this to accept many. -->
  <div class="item draggable">1</div>
  <div class="item draggable">2</div>
  <div class="item draggable">3</div>
  <div class="item draggable">4</div>
</div>
<div id="list2" class="droppable list" data-max="3"><!-- I want this to accept only 3. -->
  <div class="item draggable">5</div>
  <div class="item draggable">6</div>
</div>
<div id="list3" class="droppable list" data-max="3"><!-- I want this to accept only 3. -->
  <div class="item draggable">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The .selected can still add more than 3 to each list. Any ideas on how to prevent that? 

I changed the `$(".droppable").droppable` ...  `if($selected.length > 1)` to `if($selected.length <= 3)`, and it seemed to work, but it can still add more than 3 to each list and leaves the draggables selected.

Comment: I don't really understand this comment. Can you please clarify?

Comment: If you click on the draggable, but don't move it, it gets selected and changes color. You can select as many as you want and then move them all at once. (This was something I just realized myself.) I thought I could fix it by changing the `if($selected.length > 1)` line under the droppables to `if($selected.length <=3)`, but it didnt work.

Comment: I dont see any color changed and I dont understand how you select "as many as you want".

Comment: Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nancy76/3d9gk1r4/). It has the same code from my question, with your edit. If you click on 1-4 and then drag them to the box with #7, it will have 5 items in that box.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Thank you again.

Comment: Glad I could help :)